# ReactJS show/hide div with buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have:

MainScreen:

```
import React from 'react';
import LeftNavigation from './LeftNavigation';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MainScreen">
                <DocumentTitle title='Main Screen'>
                    <LeftNavigation />
                    <RightPanel />
                </DocumentTitle>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

LeftNavigation:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tab from './Tab';

export default class LeftNavigation extends React.Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            active_tab: 'basics'
        })
    }

    onClick(e) {
        this.setState({
            active_tab: e
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="tab-container">
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'basics')} name="Basics" icon="basics.png" active={this.state.active_tab == 'basics'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'rooms')} name="Rooms" icon="room.png" active={this.state.active_tab == 'rooms'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'documents')} name="Documents" icon="documents.png" active={this.state.active_tab == 'documents'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'images')} name="Images" icon="images.png" active={this.state.active_tab == 'images'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'restrictions')} name="Restrictions" icon="restrictions.png" active={this.state.active_tab == 'restrictions'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, '3d')} name="3D" icon="house.png" active={this.state.active_tab == '3d'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'video')} name="Video" icon="video.png" active={this.state.active_tab == 'video'}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want those buttons to control the visibility of divs container within RightPanel. How can I pass the active_tab state back up to LeftNavigation and then into RightPanel?

---

Some tweaks to the answer got it working:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tab from './Tab';

export default class LeftNavigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="tab-container">
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, 'basics')} name="Basics" icon="basics.png" active={this.props.activeTab == 'basics'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, 'rooms')} name="Rooms" icon="room.png" active={this.props.activeTab == 'rooms'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, 'documents')} name="Documents" icon="documents.png" active={this.props.activeTab == 'documents'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, 'images')} name="Images" icon="images.png" active={this.props.activeTab == 'images'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, 'restrictions')} name="Restrictions" icon="restrictions.png" active={this.props.activeTab == 'restrictions'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, '3d')} name="3D" icon="house.png" active={this.props.activeTab == '3d'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.props.onTabSelected.bind(null, 'video')} name="Video" icon="video.png" active={this.props.activeTab == 'video'}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

import React from 'react';
import LeftNavigation from './LeftNavigation';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';

export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: 'basics'
        })
    }

    handleTab(tab) {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: tab
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MainScreen">
                <DocumentTitle title='Main Screen'>
                    <LeftNavigation onTabSelected={this.handleTab.bind(this)} activeTab={this.state.activeTab}/>
                </DocumentTitle>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when you come across this situation you need to hoist your state up a level or two. Keeping your state as high in the component tree as possible is good practice.

In this case `MainScreen` becomes responsible for managing the active tab state and passing it down to its child components.

`LeftNavigation` can influence the active tab state by calling a prop that is passed down to it from `MainScreen`

```
export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            active_tab: 'basics'
        })
    }

    handleTab(tab) {
        this.setState({
            active_tab: tab
        })
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MainScreen">
                <DocumentTitle title='Main Screen'>
                    <LeftNavigation onTabSelected={this.handleTab.bind(this)} activeTab={this.state.activeTab} />
                    <RightPanel activeTab={this.state.activeTab} />
                </DocumentTitle>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class LeftNavigation extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        activeTab: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        handleTab: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="tab-container">
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, 'basics')} name="Basics" icon="basics.png" active={this.props.active_tab == 'basics'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, 'rooms')} name="Rooms" icon="room.png" active={this.props.active_tab == 'rooms'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, 'documents')} name="Documents" icon="documents.png" active={this.props.active_tab == 'documents'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, 'images')} name="Images" icon="images.png" active={this.props.active_tab == 'images'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, 'restrictions')} name="Restrictions" icon="restrictions.png" active={this.props.active_tab == 'restrictions'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, '3d')} name="3D" icon="house.png" active={this.props.active_tab == '3d'}/>
                    <Tab onClick={this.handleTab.bind(null, 'video')} name="Video" icon="video.png" active={this.props.active_tab == 'video'}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting "PropTypes is not defined"

Comment: I got it working with some changes, thanks for your help.